# How to parse "就算世界与我为敌"?

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm looking at the phrase: "就算世界与我为敌"
and I understand that the gist of it is: "Even against the whole world"

But, I don't fully understand how to properly parse it. In particular, the words:

与 - and / with

为 - as / because of / for

I'm not sure how they're being used here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

与 here serves as a noun conjunction (you could replace it with 和), and links 世界 and 我 forming a composite subject. Its proper translation however depends on the verb that follows, which is 为.
为 oftentimes can be rendered just as "to be". It is after all a copular verb, especially in this sentence, therefore：

就算 / (世界 / 与 / 我) / (为 / 敌)

Even if it's me against the world

However, you should also consider that 与 can work as a preposition, thus it relates to the following 我 more strongly than "pure" conjunctions, so it's also acceptable to parse it as: 
世界 / 与我
For this reason I would tend to give more prominence to 世界 semantically, therefore I think the best translation is:

Even if the world's against me

Answer (score 2):

就算 even if

世界 the world

与 and

我 I

为 as, being

敌 enemies

Comment: Is 就算 here interchangeable with 即使 and/or 那怕？

Comment: @YoavVollansky: yes I believe so.

Answer (score 1):

Although Siyi Deng has already answered it correctly, I'm just making it more clear, hope u understand, :)

In this case:

Even if         = 就算
the world     = 世界

became / enemy / with / me
     为     /     敌    /   与 /   我

Answer (score 0):

世界与我为敌 here means "the world and me are hostile". 敌 is not a noun here, in fact it's an adjective in my opinion, 敌对的 in Chinese.

If the phrase is "世界**以**我为敌", then the 敌 would be a noun means enemy.